# How to filter the list of object with list of object?

Tags: c#

I want to try to filter a list of objects with a list of objects that somehow can't implement properly. Is there an extension that can be used in filtering an object with objects?

What I try,

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyTests
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var employees = new List<Employee>();

            employees.AddRange(new List<Employee>
            {
                new Employee
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Name = "John Doe"
                },
                new Employee
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Name = "Smith Doe"
                },
                new Employee
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Name = "Jane Doe"
                }
            });

            var result = employees.Where(employee => employee.Name != new string["John Doe", "Smith Doe"]);
        }
    }

    public class Employee
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Expected Result:

Jane Doe

Comment: `!array.Any(employee.Name)` ?

Comment: Put there array of employess to filter for somewhere else and use the Contains method of the array in the where clause.  `employees.Where(employee => filteredEmployeesArray.Contains(employee));`

Comment: @Ralf a `HashSet` is more efficient here.

Comment: `result = emplyee3;` is most efficient ^^

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
    var badNames = new HashSet<string> {"John Doe", "Smith Doe"};
    var employees = new List<Employee>{
                    new Employee {Id = 1, Name = "John Doe"},
                    new Employee {Id = 2, Name = "Smith Doe"},
                    new Employee {Id = 3, Name = "Jane Doe"}};
    var goodEmployees = employees.Where(e => !badNames.Contains(e.Name));

    goodEmployees.ToList().ForEach(e => Console.WriteLine("Good one: {0}", e.Name));
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

When filtering using a Linq query, you should pass it a valid comparison.
For example:

```
var result = employees.Where(employee => employee.Name == "Jane Doe");
```

or

```
var result = employees.Where(employee => !(new [] {"John Doe", "Smith Doe"}).Contains(employee.Name));
```

which will both return you a filtered list of Employee objects, where the condition matches.

Comment: Optimisation is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I will try your suggestion.